# How to fixcrack from a print pause?

Tags: resin, anycubic-photon

I was printing a leather mold on my Anycubic Photon Mono 4k. I needed to pause the print to refill resin vat, and at the height of the pause I got a crack. Resin is washed, but not yet cured. So how do I go from here? I don't want to have to reprint it.

I was thinking about using a baby powder + resin to fill the cracks before curing, and sanding it after. But maybe there's a better way? Especially for the hollow part, as it will rest directly on the leather and any blemishes will be transferred to the finished product.

[image: Image showing the crack]